# Paypal Express - Hide Shipping Methods and Shipping Costs

Tags: paypal

I'm using PayPal Express in my shop and determine the shipping costs after the user comes back to the shop after signing in via PayPal Express.

Right now I'm passing no shipping costs, because I want to hide the entire shipping costs/methods (marked yellow) [image]

How is this possible? My current requests looks like this:

```
     ["CALLBACKVERSION"]=>
  string(4) "84.0"
  ["LOCALECODE"]=>
  string(5) "de_DE"
  ["SOLUTIONTYPE"]=>
  string(4) "Mark"
  ["BRANDNAME"]=>
  string(8) "Foo"
  ["CARTBORDERCOLOR"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["RETURNURL"]=>
  string(168) "..."
  ["CANCELURL"]=>
  string(111) "..."
  ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION"]=>
  string(4) "Sale"
  ["CALLBACK"]=>
  string(158) "..."
  ["CALLBACKTIMEOUT"]=>
  int(6)
  ["NOSHIPPING"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"]=>
  string(4) "1.19"
  ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"]=>
  string(3) "EUR"
  ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT"]=>
  string(4) "1.25"
  ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC"]=>
  string(50) "..."
  ["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM"]=>
  string(50) "..."
  ["MAXAMT"]=>
  string(5) "32.25"
  ["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0"]=>
  string(12) "Gesamtsumme:"
  ["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0"]=>
  string(4) "1.25"
  ["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0"]=>
  int(1)
```

This results in an error from PayPal

> "Flat-rate shipping options are missing; you must specify flat-rate
>   shipping options when you specify a callback URL."

But if I pass any shipping costs, it is shown as above. How can I hide them?

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: Yes, remove the callback url provides or provide correct shipping costs in the callback url solves the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that according to [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_SOAP/?mark=ShippingOptionsType#setexpresscheckout-request-fields), `FlatRateShippingOptions - ebl:ShippingOptionsType` is required if you are specifying the Callback URL.

When I look at the documentation about `ShippingOptionsType` [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/#shipping-options-type-fields), this looks like something you want to do;

> false — PayPal does not display this flat-rate shipping option and its
>   amount as the default shipping option.

There are three (plus 2) fields you need to add:

```
1. "L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULTn":
    If you specify false, you can adjust either or both of these values:
     - PAYMENTREQUEST_n_TAXAMT
     - PAYMENTREQUEST_n_INSURANCEAMT

2. "L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAMEn"
3. "L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNTn"
```

Hope this can help you!